# How do I enable a specific GNOME extension from terminal?

Tags: command-line, fedora, gnome

How can I enable a specific GNOME extension from the terminal?

Linux distribution: Fedora 34 Workstation GNOME

I want to activate "dash-to-dock" from the command line.

dash-to-dock : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

I have seen this question: [How do I enable and disable GNOME extensions from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029376/how-do-i-enable-and-disable-gnome-extensions-from-the-command-line)
But it’s for all extensions, not for just one.

I have tested this command, but it does not work.

```
pc-hostname :: username :: ~ >> gsettingsgsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com']"
pc-hostname :: username :: ~ >>
```

Comment: Add to your post the **output** generated by that command you ran on the terminal too.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry I edited my post.

No output, the command returns nothing. No error, no message, but does not activate the dash-to-dock extension.

Comment: Is the linux distro which you're trying doing that procedure **Fedora**? What's **version**? Add to you post that info too, please

Comment: Oh God I'm tired ! Linux distro : Fedora 34 Workstation Gnome. I edited my post.

Comment: Is that [extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) are you trying to enable?

Comment: Yes that extention

Comment: Did you install that extesion by **browser**? The **lastest version**, right? Did you only do that, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable that extension with:

```
gnome-extensions enable dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
```

N.B.:  I don't use that extension, but it's the usual way to to enable extensions from the command line.

Comment: Many thanks ! The command work well :-)